# Problem with scraping table using Xpath and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, geckodriver

I need to **scrape** values marked as yellow in attached picture.
I was trying to **scrape** single table cell using: `driver.find_element_by_xpath(/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div[5]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2])`

It didn't work. I was trying as well to use below code:

```
table = driver.find_elements_by_id("recommendationTable")
    with open('scraper.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
        for row in table.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr'):
            wr.writerow([d.text for d in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')])
```

It didn't work either.
At the picture there is as well this table HTML.
I want to **scrape** these yellow values and save each of them at the Excel columns.

[HTML of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysFib.png)

Do you have any idea how to **scrape** this thing?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: This is a link to the page: https://www.bankier.pl/inwestowanie/profile/quote.html?symbol=CCC

Answer (score 0):

The id recommendationTable don't exist in the link you provide. 
Did you try to get the table by passing the class name to the xpath ?

```
 table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='marketInfo']")
 with open('scraper.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in table.find_elements_by_xpath('.//tbody/tr'):
        wr.writerow([d.text for d in row.find_elements_by_xpath('.//td')])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath to handle your first row :

```
driver.get('https://www.bankier.pl/inwestowanie/profile/quote.html?symbol=CCC')
driver.maximize_window()

tabel = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='marketInfo']//tbody//tr[1]")))

print tabel.text
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer if your issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use **pandas** to `read_html()` and load into `DataFrame` and then import into **csv**.

If you don't have pandas.Very simple step to install.

> pip install pandas

**Code**:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="path\to\gecodriver")
driver.get("https://www.bankier.pl/inwestowanie/profile/quote.html?symbol=CCC")
table=WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".marketInfo"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")
df=pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
df.to_csv("scraper.csv",index=False)
```

Csv file after generating

[image]